# Why are the AF SF IF flags set in this program

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, nasm

```
section .data
hello:     db 'hello world!',10,13
helloLen   equ $-hello

section .text
    global main

main:
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,hello
    mov edx,helloLen
    int 80h

    mov eax,1
    mov ebx,0
    int 80h
```

When I debug this line by line right from the start the AF SF IF flags are set in the EFLAGS register

Comment: I guess it's because the EFLAGS register's state is mostly undefined at program start.

Comment: I thought it could be the flags default values but I couldn't find information on that anywhere

Comment: Usually in assembly at entry point there are rarely any stringent defaults, and even if they are, they are often changed/broken with future versions of particular OS/platform, like within a decade or so, so it's better to initialize almost everything.

Comment: From the presence of the `main` symbol, I *guess* you are using the CRT (even if you don't need it). Both the SYS V i386 and AMD64 ABI define the initial value of the status flags as 0 (IF is not a status flag, is a control flag, and a user mode program should never see it zero), thus AF and SF must be set by the CRT initialization. Simply put: your code is not the first thing to run in your process.